# Getting 404 error for certain stocks and pages on yahoo finance python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, http-status-code-404

I am trying to scrape data from yahoo finance at this URL https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL. After running the python code below, I get the following HTML response

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml
from lxml import html

stockStatDict = {}
stockSymbol = 'AAPL'
URL = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+ stockSymbol + '/key-statistics?p=' + stockSymbol
page = requests.get(URL)
print(page.text)


<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en-us"><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Yahoo</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimal-ui">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      <style>
  html {
      height: 100%;
  }
  body {
      background: #fafafc url(https://s.yimg.com/nn/img/sad-panda-201402200631.png) 50% 50%;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      font: 300 18px "helvetica neue", helvetica, verdana, tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
  }
  table {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
      border: none;
  }
  h1 {
      font-size: 42px;
      font-weight: 400;
      color: #400090;
  }
  p {
      color: #1A1A1A;
  }
  #message-1 {
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 0;
  }
  #message-2 {
      display: inline-block;
      *display: inline;
      zoom: 1;
      max-width: 17em;
      _width: 17em;
  }
      </style>
  <script>
    document.write('<img src="//geo.yahoo.com/b?s=1197757129&t='+new Date().getTime()+'&src=aws&err_url='+encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+'&err=%<pssc>&test='+encodeURIComponent('%<{Bucket}cqh[:200]>')+'" width="0px" height="0px"/>');var beacon = new Image();beacon.src="//bcn.fp.yahoo.com/p?s=1197757129&t="+new Date().getTime()+"&src=aws&err_url="+encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+"&err=%<pssc>&test="+encodeURIComponent('%<{Bucket}cqh[:200]>');
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- status code : 404 -->
  <!-- Not Found on Server -->
  <table>
  <tbody><tr>
      <td>
      <img src="https://s.yimg.com/rz/p/yahoo_frontpage_en-US_s_f_p_205x58_frontpage.png" alt="Yahoo Logo">
      <h1 style="margin-top:20px;">Will be right back...</h1>
      <p id="message-1">Thank you for your patience.</p>
      <p id="message-2">Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue.</p>
      </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>
  </body></html>
```

I am confused, because I had no problem scraping the data on the summary tab at this URL https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL using the following code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml
from lxml import html
stockDict = {}

stockSymbol = 'AAPL'
URL = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+ stockSymbol + '?p=' + stockSymbol
page = requests.get(URL)
print(page.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


stock_data = soup.find_all('table')

stock_data
for table in stock_data:
    
    trs = table.find_all('tr')
    
    for tr in trs:
        
        
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        
        if len(tds) > 0:
         
            stockDict[tds[0].get_text()] = [tds[1].get_text()]


stock_sum_df = pd.DataFrame(data=stockDict)
print(stock_sum_df.head())
print(stock_sum_df.info())
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm also using the free version of yahoo finance if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 15):

So I figured out your problem.

> The User-Agent request header contains a characteristic string that allows the network protocol peers to identify the application type, operating system, software vendor or software version of the requesting software user agent. Validating User-Agent header on server side is a common operation so be sure to use valid browser’s User-Agent string to avoid getting blocked.
>
> **Source**: http://go-colly.org/articles/scraping_related_http_headers/)

The only thing you need to do is to set a legitimate user-agent. Therefore add headers to emulate a browser:

```py
# This is a standard user-agent of Chrome browser running on Windows 10 
headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36' }
```

Example:

```py
import requests 
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}
stockSymbol = 'AAPL'
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+ stockSymbol + '/key-statistics?p=' + stockSymbol
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5).text 
print(resp)
```

Additionally, you can add another set of headers to pretend like a legitimate browser. Add some more headers like this:

```py
headers = { 
    'User-Agent'      : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36', 
    'Accept'          : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'DNT'             : '1', # Do Not Track Request Header 
    'Connection'      : 'close'
}
```

These things usually kick in due to 2 main reasons:

1. Anti-automation systems (systems that detect bots/crawlers)
2. Sites that tend to moderate content based upon the browser that you're visiting with.

Hence, it is always a good idea to supply a user-agent in the headers when designing automation systems.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure as to what causes the issue and what the intent is of your project. However if your intent is to be able to do something with yahoo finance data - and not to learn how to scrape data, than the following module could help you out (https://pypi.org/project/yahoo-finance/)